# Js take the days of the last n months

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time, luxon

This code gives me the days of the last 3 months, but I would like to try to optimize it, make it faster if possible.

Can you give me some advice?

```html
<script type="module">
import {DateTime} from 'https://unpkg.com/luxon@2.3.1/src/luxon.js';
console.time('Time')

const lNow = DateTime.now()
const lThreeMonthsAgo = lNow.minus({ month: 3 }).startOf('week')
let lastDays = []
let ii = 0
while (
  Math.floor(lNow.diff(lThreeMonthsAgo.plus({ days: ii }), 'days').days) >= 0
) {
  lastDays.push(lThreeMonthsAgo.plus({ day: ii }))
  ii = ii + 1
}

console.timeEnd('Time')
console.log(lastDays)
</script>
```

After a few tries I got this, what do you think?

```html
<script type="module">
import {DateTime} from 'https://unpkg.com/luxon@2.3.1/src/luxon.js';
console.time('Time')

const lNow = DateTime.now();
const lThreeMonthsAgo = lNow.minus({ month: 3 }).startOf("week");
let num = Math.ceil(lNow.diff(lThreeMonthsAgo, "days").days);
let lastDays = [...Array(num).keys()].reduce(
  (acc, val) => [...acc, lThreeMonthsAgo.plus({ day: val })],
  []
);

console.timeEnd('Time')
console.log(lastDays)
</script>
```

Comment: There seems to be more logic than you describe? What is this start of the week about? Does the output array *have* to consist of Luxon date instances? Why not use native date objects or date strings?

Comment: @trincot: An element at the end is something similar if you look at output: `2021-12-20T00:00:00.000+01:00`

Comment: You can also not use luxun, it is important to get the same result in the shortest possible time.

Comment: for example i did this, second function, what do you think: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-euclid-ctqo6k?file=/src/App.js

from the printed time it seems faster, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What running times are we talking about (not including the time for I/O)? Can you specify in the question what output you expect in terms of start-of-week. You didn't mention it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can possibly gain some speed by not using the luxon library, but just native Date objects:

```js
let now = new Date();
let start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() - 3, now.getDate());
// If date "overflowed" into next month, then bring it back:
if ((start.getMonth() + 3) % 12 != now.getMonth()) {
     start.setDate(0); // Go to last day of previous month
}
// Go to previous Monday if not yet a Monday
start.setDate(start.getDate() - (start.getDay() + 6) % 7); 
let lastDays = [];
while (start < now) {
    lastDays.push(start.toLocaleDateString("en-SE")); // Format YYYY-MM-DD
    start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1); // Next day
}
console.log(lastDays);
```

Comment: You need to be a bit careful with subtracting months like that. If the start date is 31 May 2022, *start* will be set to 31 Feb which becomes 3 Mar. I think Luxon will go to 28 Feb. The effect is somewhat attenuated by the subsequent shift to the start of the week (which coincidentally gives 28 Feb), but will occasionally result in the wrong week.

Comment: I don't know what luxon will do. I have asked the Asker in comments that they specify how it should work, but they haven't done so. Anyway, I have added code to counter that effect.

Comment: Indeed, just checked, Luxon goes to 28 Feb in that case. This is now covered in my answer.

Comment: @trincot: Perfect, in the end I rewrote it like this: https://pastebin.com/7MJtGkDZ

Comment: NB: that `diffDays` calculation can go wrong if day light saving works against you.